# Managing qcow2 images with virsh

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, qcow2

I have some `qcow2` images which I am starting / stopping manually, with `kvm`, like this:

```
kvm -m 256 -smp 1 -drive file=/var/VMs/qcow2/server1.qcow2 -nographic -net nic,macaddr=52:54:00:11:34:55,vlan=0 -net tap,vlan=0,ifname=tap1,script=no,downscript=no
```

Now I would like to start managing those images with `virsh`, so that I can start doing things like:

```
virsh list
virsh start YourGuestName
....
```

I have found no information on how to put my `qcow2` images under the control of `virsh`. Is there any way to do this? I would very much appreciate a solution which does *not* require reinstalling the VMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy - create and define a new VM with `virsh edit`, `virt-manager` or `virt-install`, and instead of creating the new disk images, attach the existing ones. You will need to move the images into libvirt's image store, or define an image store where the existing images are kept.